# Parsing nmap -oG output using sed

Tags: linux, bash, parsing, sed, nmap

I have a logfile

```
...
Host: 111.222.121.123 (111.222.121.123.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com) Ports: 80/open/tcp//http//AkamaiGHost (Akamai's HTTP Acceleration|Mirror service)/, 443/open/tcp//ssl|http//AkamaiGHost (Akamai's HTTP Acceleration|Mirror service)/
Host: 1.2.3.4 ()  Ports: 80/open/tcp//http//cloudflare/, 443/open/tcp//ssl|https//cloudflare/, 2052/open/tcp//clearvisn?///, 2053/open/tcp//ssl|http//nginx/, 2082/open/tcp//infowave?///, 2083/open/tcp//ssl|http//nginx/, 2086/open/tcp//gnunet?///, 2087/open/tcp//ssl|http//nginx/, 2095/open/tcp//nbx-ser?///, 2096/open/tcp//ssl|http//nginx/, 8080/open/tcp//http-proxy//cloudflare/, 8443/open/tcp//ssl|https-alt//cloudflare/, 8880/open/tcp//cddbp-alt?///
Host: 2.3.4.5 (a104-96-1-61.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com)   Ports: 53/open/tcp//domain//(unknown banner: 29571.61)/
...
```

I need to extract and convert IPs and http ports to the following format

```
1.2.3.4:80,443,2083
```

There are just two types of *port* fields in the logfile

```
80/open/tcp//http
2083/open/tcp//ssl|http
```

Tried to use `sed` but without success. I ended up with this dysfunctional command

```
cat ../host_ports.txt | sed -rn 's/Host: ([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}).*?([0-9]{1,5}\/open\/tcp\/\/http|[0-9]{1,5}\/open\/tcp\/\/ssl\|http).*/\1 \2/p'
```

Comment: Instead of trying to do it all in a single line. Attempt to write a script to extract each of the desired values, save them as variables and concatenate the strings into the desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First handle the repeating ports, and next replace Host/Port to the desired format.

```
sed -r 's/(Ports:|,) ([0-9]*)[^,]*/\1\2/g;s/Host: ([^ ]*).*Ports:/\1:/' ../host_ports.txt
```

EDIT:
First I gave all ports of a line with http somewhere, now limit the result to ports with `http` in its description.

```
sed -nr 's/Ports: /, /;
         s/, ([0-9]*)[^,]*http[^,]*/,\1/g;
         s/,[^,]*\/[^,]*//g;
         s/Host: ([^ ]*)[^,]*,/\1:/p'       ../host_ports.txt
```

Comment: This prints even non-http ports if there is `http` string in the line.

Comment: @PetrJavorik Edited my answer.

Comment: `s/Ports: /,/` must be `s/Ports: /, /` to match `http` port if it's the first port on the line.

Answer (score 1):

This script will do it for you, and you don't need `sed` :

```sh
#!/bin/bash

while read -r line; do
    if echo $line | grep -q "http"; then
        host=$(echo "$line" | grep -Po '(?<=^Host: )[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+')
        ports=$(echo "$line" | grep -Po '[0-9]*((?=\/open\/tcp\/\/http)|(?=\/open\/tcp\/\/ssl\|http))' | tr '\n' ',')
        echo "$host:${ports:0:-1}"
    fi
done < ../log
```

The first grep will catch the IP address, with the help of [Look behind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). the `-P` is to use perl like regex, and the `-o` is to output only the matching string

The second regex is much like the first, but uses look after instead of look behind. It will only capture ports which are followed by `/open/tcp//http` or `/open/tcp//ssl|http`. The `tr` right after will replace newlines with commas.

the `${ports:0:-1}` is just to eliminate the trailing comma.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for looking into that. I just edited your script to match even lines with `http-proxy` and skip lines without any `http` string.

Comment: For large files you will have performance issues when you call `grep` 3 times for every line.